# Linux mv command for moving multiple files with different extensions

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I am wondering if it possible to use bash to `mv` multiple files with different extensions into one directory, for example
`mv 1.png 2.jpg dir/`

except match many files

Comment: Or you could use wildcards like mv * dir/ which will move all files at your current path into that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)! A glob is a pattern that expands to multiple file names. It's also very nicely [explained here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern).

For example `*` matches any string of any length, and you could move all JPG and PNG files somewhere with:

```
mv *.jpg *.png dir
```

Using the `extglob` option in Bash, you could also do:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv *(*.jpg|*.png) dir
```

Comment: True, I removed the `find` example. I wrote it before I had coffee :)

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way would be to use a mix of brace expansion and globbing

```
mv -iv -- *.{png,jpg} dir/
```

Which gets expanded to

```
mv -iv -- *.png *.jpg dir/
```

Which gets expanded to (all files -- including dirs/symlincs -- ending in `.png` or `.jpg`)

```
mv -iv -- 1.png 2.jpg ... dir/
```

Note: `-iv --` is including for safety/verbosity

```
-i, --interactive
       prompt before overwrite
-v, --verbose
       explain what is being done
[GETOPT] The special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning 
         regardless of the scanning mode. 
         (Meaning everything after it gets treated as an argument)
```

Comment: if there are only .jpg files I get `no matches found: *.jpg`

Answer (score -1):

yes, it does.

```
$ tree
.
├── a.png
├── b.jpg
└── dir

1 directory, 2 files
$ mv a.png b.jpg dir
$ tree
.
└── dir
    ├── a.png
    └── b.jpg

1 directory, 2 files
$
```

mv do not care for file extentions, all it knows is the original file and the target directory requested by you.

Comment: The OP was asking about matching *many* files.